# Access GraphDatabaseService intance in java application

Tags: java, csv, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to read graph.db in my JAVA that was created in NEO4j, but when I try to access using

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
.newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder( testDirectory.graphDbDir() )
.loadPropertiesFromFile( pathToConfig + "neo4j.conf" )
.setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.read_only, "true" )
.setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.keep_logical_logs, "false" )
.setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.auth_enabled, "false" )
.newGraphDatabase();
```

Above GraphDatabaseService instance is null.
But when try to create a database directly using JAVA

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
.newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder( testDirectory.graphDbDir() )
.setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.read_only, "true" )
.setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.keep_logical_logs, "false" )
.setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.auth_enabled, "false" )
.newGraphDatabase();
graphDB.execute(cypher query)
```

Then I'm able to initiate GraphDatabaseService instance.

I want to find a particular node using

```
Node src = graphDB.findNode(Label, Key, Value)
```

src node is null when I try to read the database that was created in NEO4j server, While when I try to access it when I created database using JAVA then I'm able to access it

Comment: Show the error logs, including stack traces.

Comment: So I'm basically trying to find a node from this database using

    Transaction tx = graphDB.BeginTx()

    Node src = graphDB.findNode(LABel, "NodeKey", "Value")

and I'm getting null in src 
P.S. NodeKey and Value are present in database

Comment: That is very different than what is stated in your question. Please update your question.